# Digital Sign in

Tags: c#

I have developed a class library (Image Viewer) in VS2010 and created a setup/msi,  with have that created a .cab file using cabarc.exe and integrated in a website and working fine on all machines (including client machines).

we have got a new certificate in .pfx file format from verisign and signed-in all files (viewer.dll, setup.exe, Viewer.msi and other third party dlls like abcpdf8.dll) in setup without any issues/errors. And added the certificate with following code in class file without fail.

```
        **X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher/TrusetedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(cert);
            store.Close();
        }**
```

Verified all dlls and exe/msi successfully.

The issues are:

1. It is not available in "Available controls" in License Package Authoring Tool (LPK_Tool.exe) to create .lpk file for this control.
2. It is showing in Manage Add-ons (Internet Explorer) as **(Not Verified) Publisher Name**.
3. It is showing security warning like "An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want allow this interaction?"

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
jhon

Comment: The code snippet you give - where are you using this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.For future reference, please don't add signatures to your post. [StackOverflow already shows one for you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: I am using this code in the constructor.